# How to set nulls the values of column B and column C if they already exist on column A sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, conditional-statements, repeat

```
Select BillName as A, ConsigneeName as B, ShipperName as C 
                              from Sum_Orders 
                              where (OrderStatus in ('Complete','Invoiced')
    ) 
    and 
    OrderPeriodYear IN (
    (
    YEAR(GETDATE())-1
    )
    )
    Group by billname,ConsigneeName,ShipperName
```

I'm having duplicates in A, B, C (which is expected)
I'm trying to make a condition to 
**keep the value in A and set to nulls the values that repeat in B OR C**

IF A = B or C then keep A and SET B or C to NULLS

[image]

Thank you, guys, :D

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
update t
    set B = (case when B <> A then B end),
        C = (case when C <> A then C end)
    where B <> A or C <> A;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this inline the perhaps a case will help.

```
Select Billname AS A, 
CASE WHEN ConsigneeName = Billname THEN NULL ELSE ConsigneeName END, 
CASE WHEN ShipperName = Billname THEN NULL ELSE ShipperName 
from Sum_Orders etc ...
```

If the table is big, this maybe expensive on the query and pushing this logic into the query itself might be better.

Answer (score 0):

If a,b and c has same value, b and c should set null, so:

```
 Update tablename
 Set B = if(A=B, null, B) , C=if(A=C, null, C)
 -- where A=B or A=C
```

You can use 'where' if optimization is interesting!

If you're going to 'Select' value:

```
 Select  A, if(A=B, null, B) as B , if(A=C, null, C) as C from tablename
```